# d3 example does not work on a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, error-handling

i am trying to created this d3 visual on a **html** page

But on the html page it is displaying null !

http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/f8R3M/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=f8R3M

I have put all the codes exactly like the example ---

This is my code on the beginning ---

```
<html>
   <head>

     <script src='http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js'></script>
      <script src='Chart.min.js'></script>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>

   </head>


<script type="application/json" id="mis">
```

Rest are the exact copy from the example !

I belive in the javascript part on fiddle it is mentioned that the **d3** should be loaded on load and i don't know how i can do that on a html page ...

Can anyone solve this from on a **html** file !

Comment: How exactly to you open that html file?

Comment: So, when you debugged this with your browser's developer tools, what was the error?

Answer (score 0):

## Reorder you script

You must load **d3js-lib** before **Chart.min.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js'></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js">    </script>
    <script type="application/json" id="mis">

    <script src='Chart.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```